# Как присвоить ссылке html файл asp net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Изучаю AspNetCore 6 с помощью metanit. Возникли трудности - каким образом можно присвоить определённой ссылке, которая задается с помощью метода Map определенный html файл.
К примеру по ссылке example.net/Home выдать файл contact.html.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен что вы это искали, но на сколько я знаю html страницы маппятся к действиям контроллеров https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0 (Тут подробнее)

```
Например: файл index.html в папке Home будет мапиться к методу Index() в HomeController.cs


Program.cs:

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Предыдущий пример является примером обычного маршрута. Это называется обычной маршрутизацией, потому что она устанавливает соглашение для URL-адресов:

Первый сегмент пути, `{controller=Home}`, соответствует имени контроллера.
Второй сегмент, `{action=Index}`, соответствует названию действия.
Третий сегмент, `{id?}` используется для необязательного идентификатора. Этот знак `?` в `{id?}` делает его необязательным. идентификатор используется для сопоставления с объектом модели.

Используя этот маршрут по умолчанию, путь URL:

`/Products/List` сопоставляется с `ProductsController.List`
`/Blog/Article/17` сопоставляется с `BlogController.Article` и, как правило, модель привязывают параметр id к 17.

Comment: А есть способ используя метод статических фалйлов и метода Map?

Comment: зачем? это стандарт @Keks

Comment: я к тому что если делать на чистом core данным способом `void Contact(IApplicationBuilder appBuilder)
{
    appBuilder.Run(async (context) => 
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
        await context.Response.SendFileAsync("wwwroot/contact.html");
    });
}`  и объявлять с помощью `app.Map("/Homet" , home)` не работают стили и прочее.Зашел спросить сюда есть ли альтернативный способ.

Comment: @keks то есть ты хочешь просто запустить html страницу c css? А asp net зачем тут? Можно просто в браузере открыть это

Comment: Если автор вопроса использует ASP.NET Core Razor Pages, а не MVC то там можно просто создавать страницы Razor, с пустыми обработчиками, не заморачиваюсь написанием контроллеров. Вот в этом [репозитории](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Abby),  пример работающего приложения на Razor Pages для .NET 6. И я думаю что Автору более подойдет такая архитектура, она чуть ближе к традиционному подходу, где сначала пишется код для Веб страницы, а потом пишутся костыли чтобы как то наполнить ее корректными данными.

Answer (score 0):

На странный вопрос, странный ответ. по ссылке example.net/Home, вы можете выдать разметку Home, которая содержит полную копию файла  contact.html. Но как уже было сказано другими, а зачем вам вообще ASP для этого? ASP.NET и ASP.NET Core, это про динамическую генерацию содержимого веб-страниц, а не про выдачу статического контента. Сама аббревиатура ASP, расшифровывается как Active Script Page.